# Connection showing up, but doesn't load anything (DNS resolution fail)

Tags: kali-linux, dns, wlan

Wireless drivers installed, NetworkManager working, but nothing will load up on firefox/anything OTA

wlan0 shows up, built in wireless card, and through settings - network, it says i am connected wirelessly, but nothing will load up on internet. Even when connected to ethernet.

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 3c:07:54:3c:08:3a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 16  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 24  bytes 1664 (1.6 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 24  bytes 1664 (1.6 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.53  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::dd5b:7d61:4623:70a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether b8:8d:12:2d:fc:82  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 376  bytes 84045 (82.0 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 85  bytes 11346 (11.0 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`ping facebook.com`:

```
ping: facebook.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

`ping 31.13.81.36`:

```
PING 31.13.81.36 (31.13.81.36) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 31.13.81.36: icmp_seq=2 ttl=84 time=40.1 ms
64 bytes from 31.13.81.36: icmp_seq=3 ttl=84 time=41.4 ms
64 bytes from 31.13.81.36: icmp_seq=4 ttl=84 time=41.9 ms
64 bytes from 31.13.81.36: icmp_seq=5 ttl=84 time=40.5 ms
64 bytes from 31.13.81.36: icmp_seq=6 ttl=84 time=40.3 ms
64 bytes from 31.13.81.36: icmp_seq=7 ttl=84 time=39.2 ms
^C
--- 31.13.81.36 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 6 received, 14% packet loss, time 6032ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 39.294/40.613/41.901/0.874 ms
```

Comment: Try `nslookup stackexchange.com`.

Comment: Please add output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` to your question. I think your DNS servers are up the spout.

Comment: @roaima fair enough, also for the cat command, it just says no such file or directory

Comment: @tomas just says connection timed out, no servers could be reached

Comment: `sudo apt-get install resolvconf`

Comment: @tomas good call, but that's likely to fail without nameservers to reach the respositories.

Comment: @roaima It's likely to work with anything like `dhclient` and a DHCP server on the router. `resolvconf` creates `/etc/resolv.conf` as a link to a dynamic `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`.

Comment: @tomas if that was the case the file shouldn't have been missing in the first place.

Comment: @roaima *If this file does not exist, only the name server on the local machine will be queried; the domain name is determined from the hostname and the domain search path is constructed from the domain name.* http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html

Comment: @tomas likelihood of a local name server running if `resolv.conf` is missing?

Comment: @roaima Similar to one of it running when it's not missing? http://serverfault.com/a/634811/366920

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Internet connection is working, as evidenced by the `ping 31.13.81.36`. What's missing is the DNS name lookup, which is why `ping facebook.com` fails. I can't explain why you have nothing in `/etc/resolv.conf` but this should get you started.

Create the missing `/etc/resolv.conf` with this as a reasonable starting point

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```